# Какой тип activity выбрать для игры в андроид студио?

Tags: android-studio, разработка-игр, шаблоны

Есть ли разница какой шаблон выбрать для игры в android studio?

При выборе game activity можно выбрать поддержку только начиная с 11 версии андройда, который поддерживается 54 % устройств. Для empty activity  можно выбрать более ранние версии что обеспечит поддержку для вплоть до 100 % устройств.  Конечно хочется чтоб игра поддерживалась на максимальном количестве устройств, что выбрать?